# OpenSSL SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, nvm

I'm trying to install `nvm` on my computer. I'm running linux feature on windows 10. When I run the command `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash` I get the error message `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443`

I tried to reset the proxy settings as mentioned in a topic with the same subject, but I did not succeed in solving the problem. I saw that there are some solutions to this, but none of them mention that linux is running on windows. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was seeing the same error on my machine. It turned out to be my antivirus program. I'm using Kaspersky...

The fix for me was the following:

1. Open Kaspersky.
2. Click the gear icon at the bottom left.
3. Click "Additional" tab and go to the "Network" settings.
4. Choose "Do not scan encrypted connections."
5. Restart windows and try the curl download again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: After lots of googling and resetting Ubuntu OS, this solution resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on WSL 2. Just add the virtual Hard Disk as a trusted application in Kasperky for "Encrypted Traffic Scanning".[Click on Trusted Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXGav.png)
Click of Trusted Applications. Navigate to User/YourUserFolder/AppData/Packages/YourDistroNameFolder/LocalState/YourDistroVHDKfile.
Add and save.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem will happens on `git`, `nvm`, `rbenv` and `asdf`, etc

The root cause is these problems tries to download some file for you automatically, and you are behind some GFW or something else that will pollute your DNS.

Don't try to modify the `/etc/hosts` file. try this:

1. under stand the related bash file
2. find the source code where it used the `curl` command
3. manually download the resource and comment out the `curl` command.

e.g. in `asdf` , when you are trying to `asdf install erlang`, it will first check `kerl` if exists,  and the version is matched. if not, it will download `kerl` like this:

[image]

and the `download_ker()` function looks like:

```
download_kerl() {
    # Print to stderr so asdf doesn't assume this string is a list of versions
    echo "Downloading kerl..." >&2
    local kerl_url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kerl/kerl/${KERL_VERSION}/kerl"
    curl -Lo "$(kerl_path)" $kerl_url
    chmod +x "$(kerl_path)"
}
```

so, let's just download the file `ker_url` listed above, and then put it into the correct position, and then `chmod +x <file>`, then re-run the `asdf install erlang`, evething would be fine.